# How do I display a jpeg image stored in a core data database using html

Tags: html, ios, core-data

I have several images soared in a core data database in this way. The entity is named note.

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
    image = nil; // free memory
    [self createNote];
    note.photo_jpeg = imageData;
```

How do I reference the images in html generated for a web page to display several of these images? I think I need something like this, but I don't know what to put in the IMG SRC=...

```
        NSString *imageHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<IMG SRC="what do i put here!!!" ALT="Photo" WIDTH=%i HEIGHT=%i>", , )];
        [html appendString:imageHtml];
```

Update This is the solution I used:

```
        [html appendFormat:@"<img alt=\"Embedded Image\" src=\"data:image/jpg;base64,%@\" WIDTH=400 />", [currentNote.photo_jpeg base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
```

Where currentNote is of type note and is indexed through the notes I am displaying.

Comment: how you will show this html ?

Comment: I'm generating html to email. I needs to be html for other reasons as well. I've updated my question to include the solution.

Comment: oh, yea for email inline images good solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put the image data inline with the HTML, encoded as base64.

Something like this:

```
NSData *imageData = // from your code
NSMutableString *html = // mutable string with whatever else you need

[html appendFormat:@"<img alt=\"Embedded Image\" src=\"data:image/jpg;base64,%@\" />", [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
```

Keep in mind that this duplicates the image data, so if you're using a lot of images this way, make sure to watch how much memory you're using.

Answer (score 1):

NSData have required methode to get base64 string.

img src="data:image/jpg;base64,HereBase64RepresentationOfYourJPG"

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a way to have HTML dip into core data.

I would create a sub-directory for your core data store.  In that subdirectory, create a sibling directory to hold your images.

You can store the images as plain jpeg files, and keep the path or bookmark-url to the file in your core data object.

This way, you can still access everything via core data, and the file is available to the HTML as well.

Just include the path to the file as part of the html.